# Steam wants to redownload half-downloaded game

Tags: steam, rainbow-six-siege

I was downloading Rainbow Six Siege and I added the texture pack before it finished.

I regretted it and unchecked the tick in the DLC tab, but now Steam is trying to re-download the whole game. I have about 30 GB of the game data in the downloads folder of Steam, but it won't recognize it.

Is there anything I can do to fix this? I don't have unlimited net traffic.
And i also don't have the .acf file in the downloads folder,it's been replaced, i only have the game files.

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/85744/197244)?

Comment: There is no "delete all local content",there's just uninstall.

Comment: I tried it with Uninstall and it worked, thank you very much. I had tried putting the data in the download folder but i should've put them in the common folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taken from [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/85744/197244):

After making sure that you have a copy of the game files saved somewhere else, right click on the game in your library, and under the Properties tab select "Delete all local content" (or uninstall the game). Then place the files back into the folder (which you may have to recreate, make sure it is named the same thing and is in the same location). Now try and download the game again, Steam will recognise the files that are there.

Comment: Although steam didn't recognize all the files i could recover enough, more than i'd hoped. it missed a big whopping 8GB file tho. who the hell coded this garbage?

Comment: It could be that the file was incomplete?